# Hide link to document library in Search SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search, display-template

I have requirement from customer where they want to hide the link to document library.

Marked yellow in the following picture:

[image]

Is it possible to do it? If yes, how?

Comment: The (html) templates are in a Site-Collection ``/_catalogs/masterpage/ `` Library; directory (Display Templates/Search)

Comment: You know the title "Test 1" has the same link...right?

Comment: @DannyEngelman I know where the display templates are but i cant figure out how to hide the link in the display template.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes the title has the same link.

Comment: You open the corresponding DisplayTemplate HTML file, delete the HTML you think should be deleted, test your changes... Or do some learning first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx

Comment: So do they want to remove the Title link too? What's the point of the requirement?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott No they dont want to remove the Title link. They want that the user clicks on the Title link and document opens. I tried to find link to the document library in Item display template but no luck.

Comment: You would have to change the Item_CommonItem_Body.html file (that's what the RenderBody method on the result context object is loading. This would result in a global change to all Display Templates that call RenderBody.)  It looks like it is the truncatedUrl variable.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott yes this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please mark is answered.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change the Item_CommonItem_Body.html file (that's what the RenderBody method on the result context object is loading. This would result in a global change to all Display Templates that call RenderBody.) It looks like it is the truncatedUrl variable.